# Using Sync Adapters+ Volley/RoboSpice for Syncronous processing of Network Requests

Tags: android, android-volley, android-syncadapter, robospice

My application needs to periodically request the server for new data. I have researched regarding this and many suggested to use sync adapter for syncing with the server, however my requirement changed and I need to do the following process. Is it still advisable to use sync adapters or can I use any other library to efficiently make the following Http request sequence.

```
public void onPerformSync(Account account, Bundle extras, String authority, ContentProviderClient provider, SyncResult syncResult) {

        ZipFile imageZipFile;

        /*this is a http post request and the size the zipfile is around 1Mb*/
        ZipFile resultFile=makeHttpPostRequest(String URL, String payload); 

        SomeObject result= processZipFile(resultZipFile);

        saveData(result);

         for(String url:result.getUrls()){

              /* this is a HttpGet request which returns a zip file that 
              contains 8 images , total size of zip would be around 200kb*/
              imageZipFile= makeHttpGetRequest(url); 

              saveImageZipToDisk(imageZipFile) 
         }

       }
```

As you can see I am making a Http Post request to get some data that contains the image URL's and use those URL's to make a new HttpGet request. I would need both the result from the POST and also the images for my app to run.

Is this a valid way to use sync adapters or is this totally unacceptable? or Can I use Volley/ Robo spice to spawn the image requests to multiple threads? Sorry I am being novice, but this is a scenario I have been trying to solve.

**Update:**

So after reviewing the pros and cons of Volley and Robospice, I am using volley as I could customize the code and have more control over the caching mechanism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All alternatives should be working.

With async adapters, you will get :

- async background processing in a native android process
- might be more lightweight than the app process depending on your design
- but the communication between the app and the async adapter will involve IPC which means bundling/unbundling stuff

With Volley, you will get :

- async background processing in the same process as your app, inside Volley threads
- communication between your requests and your app will be a fully double way OO channel

With RoboSpice, you will get :

- what volley provides, but requests will be executed inside an Android service
- possible easier setup of caching
- more alternatives for networking (spring android, google http client, retrofit) etc.

Comment: So between robospice and volley. Since I am downloading multiple zip files of images(each of size 300kb) do you suggest using robospice as I have heard in some threads that volley is best used for short network calls?

Comment: I think it's really up to you. Both libs have more or less the same features. All I can say you is that it would work well with RS. I am not a volley user, but chances are that it would work too.